# H2: Class not found for DexPathList (sources is an empty array)

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an Android project which uses some external libraries. Without these libraries, the application runs fine. However, when I add them, I seem to get this error in my Android app logs:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.h2.server.web.WebServlet" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

(this is thrown for each and every external lib class)

The only issue I have is that the DexPathList class doesn't seem to be recognizing and using the existing .dex files.
[apk dex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gZdM.png)

I've tried existing solutions here on StackOverflow and have had 0 success (multiDexEnabled=true, multidex dependency, instant run is disabled, cleaning caches, reinstalling, etc).

Does anyone know how these dex files are loaded internally or if there is any way I can fix this?